# Using Func<T> delegate in C#

Tags: c#, .net, lambda

Maybe my question will be too general, but I'll try to summarize everything as soon as possible.

For several days I have been teaching about delegates (Func  to be exact), but I cannot understand a few things:

**I. Case one:**

I have method `Task.Run()` which can take as a parameter `Func<TResult>`. Why, as a delegate, using a lambda expression, I can pass a method that also has parameters - in my opinion, if a method has parameters, it is not compatible with the Func  type:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
 // It's work and is ok
 Task taskOne = Task.Run(calculateOne);

 // It's work but why can i pass calculateTwo(2) as Func<TResult> ?If the parameter type is 
 // <TResult>, should the method not have any input parameters?
 Task taskTwo = Task.Run(()=> calculateTwo(2));
}

public static int calculateOne()
{
 return 1 + 9;
}

public static int calculateTwo(int t)
{
 return 1 + 9;
}
```

**II. Case two:**

In first question I can pass method with parameter as delegate when method parameter is `Func<Tresult>`. My second question is totally the opposite. Why, as a `Func <bool, int, int>` delegate, can I pass a method that takes no parameters? And why i can't pass lambda with parameters?

```
// Why this is ok, when BubleSort parameter type is Func<int,int,bool>?
// Shouldn't I put method parameters?
BubbleSort(GreatherThan);

// ERROR: Func <bool, int, int> means int and int are parameters, yet I can't pass 
// parameters like this
BubbleSort(()=>GreatherThan(1,2));

public static void BubbleSort(Func<int,int,bool> compare)
{}

public static bool GreatherThan(int first, int second)
{
 return first > second;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In both cases, the lambda expressions that you have written:

```
()=>GreatherThan(1,2)
()=> calculateTwo(2)
```

*represent functions with no parameters*, as indicated by the empty brackets `()`. It does not matter what you do *inside* the lambda expression. `() => calculateTwo(2)` represents a function with no parameters, that calls `calculateTwo(2)` as the only thing it does. Imagine these:

```
int AnonymousFunction1() {
    return calculateTwo(2);
}
bool AnonymousFunction2() {
    return GreaterThan(1, 2);
}
```

Think of as these as what you are *actually* passing to `Task.Run` by writing those lambda expressions. These functions are clearly compatible with `Func<int>` and `Func<bool>`, and not compatible with `Func<int, int, bool>`.

Answer (score 1):

Func does not accept any parameters, so you can write lambda
like this
`() => calculateTwo(1)` and it fits Func signature

To do the same with Func<int, int, bool> you need to write like this `(first, second) => GreatherThan(1,2)`

But this is an incorrect useage of the Func. It designed to pass method reference for any other code, which can call it like that

```
public static void BubbleSort(Func<int,int,bool> compare)
{
  compare(1,2); // or something else
}
```

Sorry for my language :)